# How to properly format page numbers in word 2010?

Tags: microsoft-word-2010, page-numbers

I have to folowing document:

```
page #   function           page number I want
1        cover page         i
2        table of contents  ii
3        text               1
4        text               2
5        text               3
```

I have been told that this can be achieved with sections, but I cant get it to work.
This is what I tried:

1. After the table of content, insert a "section break - next page" instead of a regular page break to create a new section after the TOC. To achieve this, position the cursor after the TOC, then go to `page layout tab`, open the `dropdown Breaks` and click `Next Page` under `Sections Breaks`.
2. Go to `insert tab`, and choose `page number` > `Bottom of page` > `Whatever style you like`. And then the tricky part, go to `insert tab`, `page number` > `format page number` and choose `continue from previous section`. But this shows numbers only on pages #2 and #4 for some reason.

I have filldled quite a lot with the `format page number` options, but can't find something I want. Do you have a way to do it ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. On the first page of each new section you have inserted using the `Next Page Insert Section` button and already inserted your page number, double click the footer.
2. On the Design Ribbon, click the `Link to Previous` button so that it is **not highlighted**. I think this is the step you haven't done: It will allow you have independent page number formatting.
3. Now in each section, click on the page number in the header or footer, then on the Design Ribbon, click `Page Number > Format Page Numbers...`
4. In this dialog, you can set your Number Format and the starting page number for each section. Click OK.
5. Repeat for each section as needed!